# ComponenWillMount happening after render for some reason in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

```
    componentDidMount() {
    const refi = database.ref("highscores");

    // Pushing sorted data to highscoreArray.
    refi.orderByChild("highscore").limitToLast(3).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        sortedHighscores = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
            sortedHighscores.push({
                "username" : child.val().username,
                "score" : child.val().highscore
            });
        });

        sortedHighscores.sort(function(a,b) {
            return a.score - b.score;
        });
        this.setState({highscoreArray : sortedHighscores.reverse()});
    });
    console.log("highscore is:", this.state.highscoreArray);
}
```

I am trying to get data from database and put it inside highscoreArray. Then I am trying to put it as a text in render. Some reason it is empty or null. This means that componentWillMount() happens after render()

Can someone explain or make this work? I am so frustrated.

I have changed the code as people have assisted me but still it is giving error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setState({ highscoreArray:sortedHighscores.reverse()})')
```

Comment: Is `.on()` a callback? The reason `sortedHighscores` is empty array is probably because you need to set the state in the `.on()` callback instead. `setState` can also be asynchronous, it's second parameter has a callback for when the state has finished being set.

Answer (score 1):

> Data stored in a Firebase Realtime Database is retrieved by attaching an asynchronous listener to a database reference

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).

So until the result is not know, the following code `this.state.highscoreArray[0]["score"].toString()` will return an error. Before to display result, check if `highscoreArray` contains some items.

Moreover, it is not a good practice to retrieve data. Take a look to the [React component lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount):

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state synchronously in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're not waiting for all the scores to be pushed before setting it to the state, if you turn componentWillMount into an async function I believe it will solve your issue:

```
async componentWillMount() {
    sortedHighscores = [];
    const refi = database.ref("highscores");

    // Pushing sorted data to highscoreArray.
    await refi.orderByChild("highscore").limitToLast(3).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        sortedHighscores.push({
            "username" : snapshot.val().username,
            "score" : snapshot.val().highscore});
    });
     sortedHighscores.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.score - b.score;
     });
    this.setState({highscoreArray : sortedHighscores.reverse()});
    console.log("highscorevvvvv", sortedHighscores);//this.state.highscoreArray) // these are EMPTY?!?!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, data is read from Firebase asynchronously. And while the data is being read, you call `setState()` with an empty array. Then when the data comes back, you add it to the array, but you don't call `setState()` anymore.

The solution is to move the call to `setState()` into the callback that fires when the data has been read (or changed):

```
    refi.orderByChild("highscore").limitToLast(3).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        sortedHighscores = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          sortedHighscores.push({
            "username" : child.val().username,
            "score" : child.val().highscore
          });
        });

        sortedHighscores.sort(function(a,b) {
            return a.score - b.score;
        });
        this.setState({highscoreArray : sortedHighscores.reverse()});
    });
```

You'll note that I listen for a `value` event, which ensures that I get all 3 scores in one go. I also clear the array before adding the scores, since this `value` callback will be called whenever the last 3 scores change. So this means that your scores will automatically update in the UI, when you for example change them in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Try it. It's fun!

Given the answers from Andrew and Hennek, you might want to put this code in `componentDidMount()`. But there too, you'll need to call `setState()` from within the callback.

Comment: Hello, I have changed my code and looking for further instructions. console.log is still giving undefined